# How to organize the information from multiple .txt files into one database on python pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

[image: result .txt file]

Above the link is a result file called "19031783_result.txt". Each .txt file contains the statistic results and I want to organise it into a database.

The output of database from all the result files should be like this:
[image: Result Database]

So I have hundreds of result files that needs to come together into one database. The last three columns are the limits for each Bin defect count for example Bin 1 limit is 10, Bin 2 limit is 5, Bin 3 limit is 3 and Bin 4 limit is 0. So Perfect means no defects, good means it's within the specs and fail means it's above the limit.

I don't have much experience in python and I need a direction in how to create this database from .txt file. Python is much better to use as it can handle a lot of data and it is quicker.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

stock_files = sorted(glob('*result.txt'))

stock_files

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, sep="\t").assign(filename = file) for file in stock_files], ignore_index = True)

df = pd.DataFrame() #this is the bit I am stuck on
```

This is my current output and I need to clean this up and turn into the database which I have a screenshot of excel spreadsheet ( [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SebTl.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/SebTl.png)

```
    Delaminated area fraction: 9.63722329310847E-06             filename  \
0   Bin1 Defect count with diameter between 1 µm a...  19031781_result.txt   
1   Bin2 Defect count with diameter between 76 µm ...  19031781_result.txt   
2   Bin3 Defect count with diameter between 301 µm...  19031781_result.txt   
3   Bin4 Defect count with diameter exceeding 1001...  19031781_result.txt   
4                                                 NaN  19031782_result.txt   
5                                                 NaN  19031782_result.txt   
6                                                 NaN  19031782_result.txt   
7                                                 NaN  19031782_result.txt   
8                                                 NaN  19031783_result.txt   
9                                                 NaN  19031783_result.txt   
10                                                NaN  19031783_result.txt   
11                                                NaN  19031783_result.txt
```

Comment: There isn't a module that I know of that will do this easily, so it's probably best to do this in a number of steps. Do you have any existing code that you've tried to get this working?

Comment: i added the module for a start up

Answer (score 1):

**Start simple** - python might not be a friend for this basic data hoover and reshape activity

Merge all files into a single file with basic OS commands, I will demonstrate with bash and Windows CMD

For bash - Install WSL and a preferred Linux distribution
Use Bash script (almost a one liner if not too many assumptions)
Read list of results files - and cat each file , and insert the file name at the start of each  - store into one single file "AllResultsFiles.txt"

```
ls -1 *_result.txt | while read fname; do cat $fname | while read _line; do echo $fname:$_line; done; done > AllResultsFiles.txt
```

For windows - slightly more involved - but this does the same - store this into a **"C:\users\me\data\mergers.cmd"** file :

```
@echo off
del /q AllResultsFilesWin.txt
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in ('dir /b *_results.txt') DO ( 
           for /f "tokens=*" %%C in ('type %%x') do echo %%x:%%C
)  >> AllResultsFilesWin.txt
```

Then run as follows

```
C:\users\me\data\> mergers.cmd
```

This will create a single file with the contents of all files, with a colon (:) delimiter - each line with the name of the original file in the first column

It will then be easily imported into a spreadsheet or a database with three columns, using colon as a delimiter

```
create table imported_results_statistics 
(Orig_filename varchar(100),
Metric varchar(200),
Value int
)
```

Once imported to a database table you can use SQL manipulation to create a new table - transposing each group of record per filename -

**(sqlite is easy enough - but would require more steps)**

```
select orig_filename
     , max(case when substring(Metric,1,4) in 'Dela' then Value) as percent_area
     , max(case when substring(Metric,1,4) in ('Bin1') then Value end) as Bin1
     , max(case when substring(Metric,1,4) in ('Bin2') then Value end) as Bin2
     , max(case when substring(Metric,1,4) in ('Bin3') then Value end) as Bin3
     , max(case when substring(metric,1,4) in ('Bin4') then Value end) as Bin4
  from imported_results_statistics
group by orig_filename
```

If you have a more powerful database kit - you can get your compacted results as follows

```
with cte_allresults as (
select orig_filename
     , max(case when substring(Metric,1,4) in 'Dela' then Value) as percent_area
     , max(case when substring(Metric,1,4) in ('Bin1') then Value end) as Bin1
     , max(case when substring(Metric,1,4) in ('Bin2') then Value end) as Bin2
     , max(case when substring(Metric,1,4) in ('Bin3') then Value end) as Bin3
     , max(case when substring(metric,1,4) in ('Bin4') then Value end) as Bin4
  from imported_results_statistics
group by orig_filename
) 
select orig_filename as scribe_no /* I assume this is meant to reflect the file name?
     , percent_area
     , Bin1 as LessThan75UM     , Bin1 as From75To300UM
     , Bin3 as From30to1MM     , Bin4 as MoreThan1MM
     , case when Bin1 + Bin2 + Bin3 + Bin4 < 10 then 0 as perfect /* (apply your  own specific ranges and rules here *
/*    ...  */
   from cte_allresults
```

for the perfect / good / fail - you can define this back in your python script

As a SQL and shell script nutter of more years than I should remember - and recently learning python - I can guarantee this method will serve you quicker -  by all means take the single file into your python script --
Generate the bash / cmd scripts as text variables in your python script
use python subprocess.call if you are going to do this regularly

Answer (score 0):

Do you think this would do the trick?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from glob import glob

stock_files = sorted(glob('*result.txt'))

# first, create an empty dataframe with the columns names you want
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['percent_area', 'less_than_75um', '75_to_300um', '301_to_1mm', 'more_than_1mm', 'perfect', 'good', 'fail'])
# create auxiliary functions to evaluate the quality of the bins
bin_limits = [10, 5, 3, 0]
check_perfect = lambda x: 1 if sum(x) == 0 else 0
check_good = lambda x: 1 if all(np.array(x) <= bin_limits) else 0
check_fail = lambda x: 1 if all(np.array(x) > bin_limits) else 0

# loop through each file
for file in stock_files:
    # read each file and split the lines with ':' delimiter to have the value for each line and convert it to float
    # store those 4 values under 'values' list variable
    values = list(
                seq(
                    pd.read_csv(
                        file, header = None
                        )
                    )\
                .map(
                    lambda x: x[0].split(':')[1]
                    )\
                .map(
                    lambda x: float(x)
                    )
                )
    
    # check the quality of the bins and store the 3 results in 'bins_quality' list variable
    bins_quality = [check_perfect(values[1::]), check_good(values[1::]), check_fail(values[1::])]

    # add a line to the DataFrame with the name of the file in the index and the above values that correspond to the defined columns
    df.loc[file] = values + bins_quality
```